# ASP.NET - Controller fails to retrieve data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I auto generated ADO.NET Entity Database Model for my angularJS application using database showed bellow:

[image: Database model]

I have a problem with displaying all results from database. When I call function to get all data from database I got this result (witch is confusing for me):

This is result from AJAX request (I don't know how and why result is HTML page/template) ...:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="contactsManager">
<head>
    <title>Contacts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-top">
        <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Contacts</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view class="example-animate-container"
         ng-animate="{enter: 'example-enter', leave: 'example-leave'}"></div>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/application/application.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/application/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/application/contactsService.js"></script>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"855308fe8e4849c09afe6746e4d4fab6"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:53083/9ef1ca62e8c144c68814e88ffffbd4a7/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Does someone knows why I am getting this output and why I am missing data from database?

Here is code that I used:

ContactsController.cs

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
    {
        ContactsEntities db = new ContactsEntities();
        //get all
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
        {
            return db.Contacts.AsEnumerable();
        }

        //get customer by id
        public Contact Get(int id)
        {
            Contact contacts = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            if (contacts == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

            }
            return contacts;
        }
        //update
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Contact contact)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
            if (id != contact.id)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        //insert
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Contact contact)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Contacts.Add(contact);
                db.SaveChanges();
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, contact);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = contact.id }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
```

and here is angularJS controller for applications frontend:

```
app.controller('ContactsController', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', 'contactsService',
    function ($scope, $http, $location, contactsService) {
        $http.get('/#/contacts/').success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.contacts = data;
           // $scope.loading = false;
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert ("An Error has occured while loading posts!");
           // $scope.loading = false;
        });
        $scope.editContact = function (id) {
            $location.path('/edit-contact/' + id);
        };

        $scope.displayContact = function (id) {
            $location.path('/display-contact/' + id);
        };


        $scope.showDetails = function (id) {
            var el = angular.element(document.getElementById('#ct-details-' + id));
            el.toggleClass('details-hidden');
        }

    }
]);
```

Comment: Are you expecting JSON data from the controller? If so, you may need to specify it as the return type.

Comment: I have followed tutorial and tutor didn't mentioned nothing about JSON data. When I display request data I got HTML output witch is wired...

Answer (score 2):

I think, below is the line that returns you the html

```js
$http.get('/#/contacts/').success(function (data) {
```

You should not use this /#/contacts/ in the url as it is rendering the contacts view's html, instead you have to use the url of the rest api service you implemented. Something like this

```js
$http.get('http://localhost:1234/contacts').success(function (data) {
```

Comment: You should not use the url http://localhost:1234/contacts as is. You have to use your rest api url there. Just I have given you an example. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: i changed:1234 to match port that asp.net link to my url

Comment: Just put the rest api url in the browser and browse and see what is the output. if still it returns 404, then you are not running the service.

Comment: when i type localhost:XXXX/contacts I got error 404 but I am using angularJS to load templates for me so /contacts triggers angularJS to load template in index.html. Do I need to change url to localhost:XXXX (without /contacts)